# Is there a way to handle dtypes of pandas.DataFrame in rows and not columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet, hdf5, feather

Big Data file formats like `parquet`, `feather` and `hdf5` are able to work with a columnar oriented table to accelerate the speed of reading columns.

In my use case I would like to switch from `netcdf4` files to a `feather` file format because I can read some columns 10 times faster than using `netcdf4`. But unfortunately I am losing dtype specification which increases the size of the file.

So my idea is to define dtypes of rows but pandas only accepting column dtypes.

Is there a way to handle DataFrames more like a columnar oriented table and specifiy dtypes for each row?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "pandas only accepting column dtypes"?

Comment: @Laurent you can only define a dtype for a column and not for a row.

Comment: My understanding is that Pandas `astype` method works for columns as well as rows, so I suppose you could transpose your dataframe and define new types for rows (columns before transposition)?

Comment: `KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.`

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframes are a collection of series objects, so you can't have more than one data type specified per column (i.e. a column with `[2, 'dog', 3]` will have the `dtype` `object` because of the string likewise `[2, 2.5, 3]` can't be type `int` because of the `2.5`.

If you want to work row-based you'll need to transpose your `DataFrame` using`df.transpose()` (or shorthand `df.T`) this will make your columns become rows. If you're importing your data you can transpose your dataframe and cast to each column to the data type you want, if it's the case that you're preparing data to be exported then at your last step before exporting transpose.

Eg:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1, 'cat', 3], 
                  'col_2': [4, 'dog', 6]},
                  index=['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3'])

>>> df
      col_1 col_2
row_1     1     4
row_2   cat   dog
row_3     3     6

# Due to the the strings both columns are dtype object
>>> df.dtypes
col_1    object
col_2    object

# Transpose the df
>>> df.T
      row_1 row_2 row_3
col_1     1   cat     3
col_2     4   dog     6

# Now our data is in columns but still dtype object
>>> df.T.dtypes
row_1    object
row_2    object
row_3    object

# We can cast our columns (originally rows) to new dtypes now
>>> df.T.astype({'row_1': 'int', 'row_2': str, 'row_3': 'int'})
       row_1 row_2  row_3
col_1      1   cat      3
col_2      4   dog      6

>>> df.T.astype({'row_1': 'int', 'row_2': str, 'row_3': 'int'}).dtypes
row_1     int64
row_2    object
row_3     int64
```